# Prove $(P(A-B) - (P(A)- P(B))) = \left\{\emptyset\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove $(P(A-B) - (P(A)- P(B))) = \left\{\emptyset\right\}$

**The Proof:**
Obiously $\left\{\emptyset\right\} \subseteq (P(A-B) \ (P(A)- P(B))) = \left\{\emptyset\right\}$

It's left to show the other direction:
Let $D$, a set such that:

$$D\in (P(A-B)-(P(A)-P(B)))$$

In particular:
$$D\in P(A-B) = P(A\cap\overline{B}) = P(A)\cap P(\overline B)$$

On the other hand,
$$D\notin (P(A) - P(B))$$

Hence,
$$D\in P(B) \cap P(\overline B) = \left\{\emptyset\right\}$$

The last implication is unclear to me.
Why is it true?

Comment: What does $P$ denote here?

Comment: @angryavian Powerset, I think. And bar = complement

Comment: And the result appears to be the set containing the empty set, not the empty set itself...

Comment: Corrected in the title. Thanks.

Comment: Also it looks like the implication is actually that $D\in P(A)\cap P(B)$

Comment: this is how it should be @abiessu

Comment: That $D\notin\dots$ has me a bit confused in the second line then...

Comment: Your title and body ask two different questions. Note that the conditions on $D$ necessitate that $D\neq\varnothing$, rendering the last equation line false; but the question as to why $\mathcal P(B)\cap\mathcal P(\overline B)=\{\varnothing\}$ is a different want, and seems to be the question in the title. (To which my answer was aimed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's clear up the statement. Recall that: $X-(Y-Z)=(X-Y)\cup (X\cap Z)$. So we have that:

$$\mathcal P(A-B)-(\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B))=(\mathcal P(A-B)-\mathcal P(A))\cup\mathcal P((A-B)\cap B)$$

But of course that $\mathcal P(A-B)$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$, so we are left with $\mathcal P((A-B)\cap B)=\mathcal P(\varnothing)=\{\varnothing\}$.

---

If you want to do this in the element-chasing method, it's also fine.

If $D\in\mathcal P(A\cap\overline B)$, then $D\subseteq A\cap\overline B\subseteq A$, therefore $D\in\mathcal P(A)$, and similarly $D\in\mathcal P(\overline B)$. On the other hand, $D\notin\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)$.

Since we have that $D\in\mathcal P(A)$ and $D\notin\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)$, it is necessarily the case that $D\in\mathcal P(B)$.

Together, this means that $D\in\mathcal P(B)\cap\mathcal P(\overline B)=\mathcal P(B\cap\overline B)=\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: Asaf, I understand the last claim by itself. Obviously $B \cap \overline {B} = \emptyset$. What I don't understand is why the two claims imply the third.

Comment: They don't. If $D\in\mathcal P(X)-\mathcal P(Y)$ then $D\neq\varnothing$, so $D\notin\{\varnothing\}$. Your title asked why "the result is $\{\varnothing\}$, which I understood as asking why the last equality holds. Hence my answer.

Comment: Maybe the notation is bad. This part of a proof which comes to the conclusion that $D\in\left\{\emptyset\right\}$. It should start with let $D$, a set..

Comment: Don't write in "math notation" what you can write clearly in words. If you clarify your question, I'll try to edit my answer to accommodate it.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific and clear.

Comment: Okay. That's much clearer now. Let me edit my answer accordingly. (Also, you have a severe problem with counting parenthesis (I recommend programming in Lisp for a while to cure that completely).)

Comment: I'll try to notice that (And maybe I should try Python :))

Comment: Much thanks, though I still don't get this line: $D\notin\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B) \implies D\in \mathcal P(B)$

Comment: What does it mean when $D\in X-Y$?

Comment: $D\in X$ and $D\notin Y$. Got it. Thank you @Asaf

Comment: Good, you're welcome.

Comment: Must be that $D\in Y$.